# Mail is not received and this error shows in log

Tags: email, magento-2.0

I'm using Dotmailer with Magento 2.2.2

```
exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message 'Connection timed 
out' in /var/www/theuniquestore/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php:277
```

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5869106/5841824)